# I am stuck at this SQL query. Don't now what to do as I am a beginner in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

- student (Std id, name, year of study, basic stipend, dept_no)
- dept (dept_name, academic_block)

I want to increase the basic stipend of 3rd year computer science department by 5000.00 per month

I tired doing

```
UPDATE <student>
SET basic stipend = basic stipend + 5000.00
WHERE dept_name IN (SELECT dept_name
                    FROM dept
                    WHERE dept_name = 3rd year computer science);
```

I don't know about the last part as `dept_name` column is from other relation and there is no common column between two relations.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Please add the appropriate tag to your question.

Comment: MySQL and Sorry, about that I don't know how to use this website still

Comment: Can you show us an example table showing current data? and an example table showing desired data?

Comment: Also, what is it you don't know about the last part? It actually looks okay to me. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: There is no data given, just these two relations. 
I think the last part's syntax is not correct. I do not know if it can be done like this

Comment: 'there is no common column between two relations'- then this cannot be done. also when comparing to a string the string needs to be quoted.  Please add the output of show create table <tablename> for both tables as text to the question